# USB ports no longer carry data

Tags: usb, hardware

A lightning bolt took out a number of devices in my home and my raspberry pi 4b 8gb seems to have been affected. All 4 USB ports still provide power to peripherals but there seems to be no data carried in either direction. HDMI and Ethernet appear to work fine. My primary use was Octoprint and the USB port on my printer also stopped working after the lightning.

I loaded up a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS and I get the desktop to display but without the ability to use a mouse or keyboard I can't get anywhere in the desktop environment. My USB keyboard lights up but isn't working.

After some research I ran `lsusb` and nothing is returned. I also tried `sudo rpi-update` followed by `sudo apt install rpi-eeprom` in the attempt to reflash the USB firmware.

At this point I'm willing to believe the hardware is the issue and I've ordered a replacement pi.

What are some of the other things that I could try to get the USB ports working?

`dmesg` returns the following lines that seem relevant:

```
[    1.653912] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.653982] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.654041] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.683448] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.683484] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.715529] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[    1.715546] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: can't setup: -110
[    1.715585] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
[    1.715624] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: init 0000:01:00.0 fail, -110
[    1.715654] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: You are likely better replacing the Pi. This only happens when hardware is damaged. Power and data are handled by different hardware. So you’d need to replace a tiny chip, if you can even buy it separately. It’ll be cheaper to replace the Pi.

Comment: I will take a SWAG: Give SSH a try from another machine, it may get you in.

Comment: Check with your insurance company, all of your stuff may be covered. If so take advantage of it, you paid for it.

Comment: @Gil I did use SSH to set up the pi as a pi-hole so this is good advice. I also got some payout from insurance and a new pi for Octoprint.